# How to properly inject revisioned assets with gulp-inject into jade templates?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, gulp, gulp-inject

I have a `node.js` app with `express` middleware. Static pages are made using `jade` template engine and get rendered on request with `res.render("template-name.jade");`

**SASS** and **javascript** files are minified and placed in `/build/js` and `/build/css` folders respectively.

Also, using `gulp` with `gulp-rev` each file get a revision string attached to its name with manifest file being created. The following task code is used for javascript files:

```
gulp.task( "prepare_js", function() {
    gulp.src( "./js/*.js" )
    .pipe( annotate() )
    .pipe( gulp_if( isDev, uglify() ) )
    .pipe( rev() )
    .pipe( gulp.dest('build/js') )  // write rev'd assets to build dir
    .pipe( rev.manifest() )
    .pipe( gulp.dest('build/js') ) // write manifest to build dir
    .pipe( gulp.dest( "./build/js") )
});
```

Task generates manigest file like:

```
{
    "index.js": "index-d41d8cd9.js"
}
```

The similar task supposed to be for compiling sass to css.

The quiestion is how to use `gulp-inject` properly (in that task or as a separate one) to find-and-replace in every .jade file only assets, defined in that .jade file with ones with revision string?

I see 2 major approaches how to solve it.

### Approach 1

Work with the same jade templates each time, and somehow define in each .jade file what file (based on original, without revision string attached, file name) should be injected. Then search lines left from previous task run and replace them with new ones, having new revision string.

For example lets say we have 2 files. Each of them may use common assets, as well as some specific ones.

```
// index.jade
script(src="/js/index-xxxxxx.js", type="text/javascript")
script(src="/js/more-js-xxxxxx.js", type="text/javascript")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/index-xxxxxx.css")


// product.jade
script(src="/js/index-xxxxxx.js", type="text/javascript") // <-- here we use index-xxxxxx.js also 
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/file1-xxxxxx.css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/file2-xxxxxx.css")
```

Let's assume here that `xxxxxx` defines revision strings left from previous gulp task. In our case, files above could be changed to add comments for **inject** like:

```
// index.jade
<!-- index.js -->
script(src="/js/index-xxxxxx.js", type="text/javascript")
<!-- one-more-js-file.js -->
script(src="/js/one-more-js-file-xxxxxx.js", type="text/javascript")
<!-- styles.css -->
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/styles-xxxxxx.css")
<!-- endinject -->


// product.jade
<!-- product.js -->
script(src="/js/index-xxxxxx.js", type="text/javascript")
<!-- file1.css -->
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/file1-xxxxxx.css")
<!-- file2.css -->
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/file2-xxxxxx.css")
<!-- endinject -->
```

This should tell gulp-inject that particular line should be changed to new one containing files with new revision string.

### Approach 2

Have 2 template folders, one having all template sources, other one with templates after running inject task. Express app will point to folder 2 as a plase to take statics from.

In all templates under first folder just add comments which file should be injected, like so:

```
// index.jade
<!-- index.js -->
<!-- one-more-js-file.js -->
<!-- styles.css -->
<!-- endinject -->


// product.jade
<!-- index.js -->
<!-- file1.css -->
<!-- file2.css -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

What would be the right solution here? And how to write/modify gulp task to properly inject assets with ones having revision string (based on generated manifest file or somehow without it)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the syntax in injecting, I think, it should be one pair for one file, e.g.

```
<!-- index.js -->
<script src="index-xxxxxx.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

And regarding why it's not injecting properly, then I think, you need to pre-process Jade file first. Try the same approach with your test HTML file and it will work. But Gulpjs need to pre-process Jade first to inject, and prior to Expressjs' own Jade compiler. [gulp-jade](https://github.com/phated/gulp-jade)